# Is there a way to write this code shorter?

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, aura

I have something like this:

```
@AuraEnabled
public String var1{get;set;}
@AuraEnabled
public Decimal var2{get;set;}
@AuraEnabled
public String var3{get;set;}
@AuraEnabled
public String var4{get;set;}
```

And I have about 20 variables needed. Is there a way to write this code shorter?
Something like this?

```
@SomeAnnotation
public String var1{get;set;}
public Decimal var2{get;set;}
public String var3{get;set;}
public String var4{get;set;}
```

Comment: I'd go with the verbose specification of the variables and the AuraEnabled annotations they need. If you REALLY don't like it, do you have groups of values of the same type that you could consider turning into a small number of arrays? NB: The problem with this approach is meaning is lost when referencing the value, of course, since all you have is a hard-coded index rather than a specific property name...

Answer (score 6):

You only need to declare @AuraEnabled once per type, if you use the comma operator to define multiple variables. In your case, you could write it as:

```
@AuraEnabled public String var1, var3, var4;
@AuraEnabled public Decimal var2;
```

You do not need to add explicit default getter-setter `{ get; set; }` in order for the variables to be accessible (this is a Visualforce-only restriction).

Comment: sfdcfox, i think setter and getter is needed by lwc, even lwc recipe uses set get.
https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/blob/master/force-app/main/default/classes/CustomWrapper.cls

Comment: I can't exactly remember the use case (shame on me) but I had a hard-to-resolve issue last year where adding `{get;set;}` to properties solved the problem. I am almost sure it was lightning-component related.

Comment: @SebastianKessel exactly, faced the same countless times. Probably there are some discrepancies in LWC and AURA engine.

Comment: @PranayJaiswal I just tested this... The getter-setter is not necessary. There may have been a bug last year, but it doesn't seem to be the case now.

Comment: @sfdcfox aha, I see makes sense now. The more you know. I will raise a feature request in lwc recipe to remove setter and getter. Thanks

Comment: We have used simple public (and public final) attributes, rather than (automatic) properties with LWC components successfully for a year or so. We did spot an issue whereby this didn't work in very specific cases - I think when we had an input parameter to an AuraEnabled method where that parameter was an inner class with AuraEnabled attributes (though I can't recall if we had the same issue whether we used attributes or properties). The solution was to make the parameter class a top-level class (with AuraEnabled public attributes).

Comment: We use apexdoc to document our code. This doesn't play well with the comma syntax, applying the one doc comment to each of the attributes in the declaration statement which is (typically) not what is wanted.

Comment: FWIW, I'm unable to get the answer to work. Anyone interested, I'd invite over to the `lwc-recipes` app and the issue that @PranayJaiswal raised. https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/issues/198

Comment: @pchittum I created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/brianmfear/1edeccb86bdd1cb1c31e16a3f405d69c) for this. If you'd like, I can also create an unlocked package?

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox. Passed in as input, attributes fail. But you're showing as response. See the gist for further comments and discussion.

Comment: @pchittum Something weird is going on. I'm getting a gack, 2101749449. Even after changing to getter/setter, the gack persists. Further research is required. I'll get back to you.

Comment: @pchittum  Sfdcfox are you all on Spring 20 or winter 20

Comment: @PranayJaiswal My dev box is Winter 20. I'm going to spin up a Spring 20 scratch org today after I get the kids from school and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: I'm working on updates to sample apps for Spring 20. So everything I'm doing is Spring 20 using the Spring 20 pre-release version of Salesforce cli. But I think I sussed it, that as _input_, you must have Apex properties no matter what. As a return value, apex types seem to support attributes. This would be a good one to bring to @ca_peterson.