# Problem passing a wrapper class from LWC to Apex

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, wrapper-class, aura-enabled

I am having trouble passing an apex wrapper class from LWC into APEX.

**Apex**

```
@AuraEnabled
public static void myMethod(SomeData theData) {
    system.debug('theData is ' + theData);
}

public class SomeData {
    public String theString;
    public Object theObject;
}
```

**LWC**

```
connectedCallback() {
    const myData= {
        'theString': 'Test',
        'theObject': true
    };
    myMethod({theData: myData})
    .then(result => {
        if (result) {
            
        }                   
    } catch(err) {
        
    }
}
```

When I run the code above what I get from APEX is `[theString=null, theObject=null]`.

However if I modify the signature of the APEX method to be `public static void myMethod(String theString, Object theObject) {` and respectively pass that from the JS side `myMethod({theString: myString, theObject: myObject})` where `myString = 'Test';` and `myObject = true` that gets parsed properly in APEX and I can see it in the debugs.

I also tried specifying the `sobjectType` when instantiating the JS object like but that didn't help either:

```
const myData= {
    'sobjectType': 'SomeData',
    'theString': 'Test',
    'theObject': true
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `@AuraEnable` your attributes.

**Incorrect**

```
public class SomeData {
    public String theString;
    public Object theObject;
```

**Correct**

```
public class SomeData {
    @AuraEnabled public String theString { get; set; }
    @AuraEnabled public Object theObject { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Oh my god, the most obvious. Thank you. One more question - why can't I access the variables without specifying `{ get; set; }` at the end? I remember VisualForce required those but I thought that for LWC all I need to do is say `@AuraEnabled`. At least that is the case if I pass them from APEX to LWC.

Comment: +1 Might also want to point out case-sensitivity, just in case.

Comment: @Arthlete The `{ get; set; }` was previously required because of a bug (discussed in [this comment chain](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/292185/2984)). I'm not sure if it got fixed. You can try it *without* implicit getter/setter, but be aware it may break.

Comment: @sfdcfox Yes without the `{ get; set; }` it will not accept the values I pass from the front end. Thank you for the link!

Comment: I think it's only passing from front end to back end where it's needed.

Comment: Yes, that was the experience I had, too.